# Laravel Query Build 2 table problem join questions (Dissolved)

Tags: laravel, relational-database

I couldn't find how to do this in Laravel

I added my tables and query

Maybe I have chosen the wrong way, I would be very happy if you share your suggestions

```
table order
id      pool_id      durum     tarih
1       1            0         2020-02-24(not start)
2       2            1         2020-02-24(started)
3       1            1         2020-02-24(started)
4       2            0         2020-02-24(not start)

table orderdetail
id      order_id      statu_id     finish
1       2             1            1
2       2             2            0
3       3             1            1
4       3             2            1
5       3             3            0
```

laravel code;

```
        $orders= Order::where('pool_id',$pool)
        ->leftJoin('orderdetails', function ($join) {
                $join->on('orderdetails.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
                        ->where('durum','=','1')
                        ->where('orderdetails.statu_id','<=','2')
                        ->where('orderdetails.finish','=','0');
                    ->where('durum','=','0')
        ->whereDate('tarih', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateString())
        ->whereDate('tarih', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->toDateString())
        ->select('orders.*')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

how to do as below

```
    if(durum == 1){
       join and condition (statu_id and finish) success get only order row
    }
    if(durum == 0){
       get only order row
    }
```

thank you for your interest Andrew Larsen

migration order

```
      Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('orderno')->unique();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('pool_id');
    $table->foreign('pool_id')->references('id')->on('pools')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('grup_id');
    $table->foreign('grup_id')->references('id')->on('testgroups');
    $table->string('vardiya');
    $table->string('tanim')->default(0);//0: plansız-1:planlı
    $table->string('durum')->default(0);//0: beklemede - 1: işlem başladı - 2: işlem bitti - 3: iptal
    $table->timestamps();
  });
```

migration orderdetail

```
     Schema::create('orderdetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
    $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('test_id');
    $table->foreign('test_id')->references('id')->on('tests');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('statu_id');
    $table->foreign('statu_id')->references('id')->on('status');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->string('finish')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
  });
```

model order

```
class Order extends Model
{
  function getPool(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pool','pool_id','id');
  }
  function getTestgroup(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Testgroup','id','grup_id');
  }

  public function user()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
  }

  public function getDetay()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Orderdetail','order_id')
        ->where('statu_id','<=','2')->where('finish','<=','0')->first();
  }
}
```

model orderdetail

```
class Orderdetail extends Model
{
  public function getOrder(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order','order_id');
  }

  public function getPool(){
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
      'App\Models\Pool',
      'App\Models\Order',
      'id', // Foreign key on users table...
      'id', // Foreign key on history table...
      'order_id', // Local key on suppliers table...
      'pool_id' // Local key on users table...
    );
  }

}
```

thanks everyone

Comment: Would recommend creating a orderdetail model define relationship and use Eloquent. Would make your life easier. And if you would like us to help you, you should add the result you are getting with your current code.

Comment: Actually, I want to use Eloquent, but I don't know how to apply it to such a situation. My models have been defined. Rules that join as output do not work. Statu_id = 3 line comes

Comment: Then that should be your question if that is what you want to achieve. Add the code of your models and migration (so we're sure the models is set-up correctly) and we can help you out.

Comment: thank you for your interest, 
I added what you want

Comment: I said you should use Eloquent, but in fact you were using Eloquent all the way. Didn't see that you were using `Order::where` in my head I saw `DB::table('...')`, my mistake. Glad we found a solution that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this function to your Order model:

```
public function orderDetails() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Orderdetail', 'order_id');
}
```

This code should do the same as your code, except this code is using eloquent instead of query builder (code not tested):

```
$orders = Order::where([
    ['pool_id', $pool],
    ['tarih', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateString()],
    ['tarih', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->toDateString()]
])
->where(function($q) {
    $q->where(function($q2) {
        $q2->where('durum', 1)
        ->whereHas('orderDetails', function($q3) {
            $q3->where([
                ['statu_id', '<=', 2],
                ['finish', 0]
            ]);
        });
    })
    ->orWhere('durum', 0);
})
->get();
```

Also in the migration file the columns `durum` and `finish` is defined as string but you are using them as if they are integers. If you want numeric values only you should define them as integers.